# Reversing a string recursively?

Tags: python, recursion

So this code reverses a string:

```
def backward(text):
if text == "":
    return text
else:
    return text[-1] + backward(text[:-1])
```

What I don't understand is how. If the text is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], won't the else statement return 5 1 2 3 4 (as [-1] is 5 and [:-1] is 1 2 3 4? I don't really get how calling the backward function reverses the [:-1] part. As you can see, I really struggle with recursive. Any assistance you can give me on this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is a list and its reverse is not `5 1 2 3 4`. Even if its a string its revers still is not `5 1 2 3 4` it'd be `"]5, 4, 3, 2, 1["`.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying- I'm saying text[-1] would be 5 and [:-1] would be 1 2 3 4. Add them together and it's 5 1 2 3 4. I know [:-1] is part of the backwards function, but I don't see how the backwards function reverses it.

Comment: One way that helps some people understand recursion is to express the code in English.  Here it's "The reverse of a string of the form S+x (any string S followed by character x) is x + reverse(S) (i.e. x moved to the front followed by S with its characters reversed."  Tracing the recursion is a pretty useless exercise, imo. The goal is to think recursively.

Comment: what do you think this `backward(text[:-1])` does?

Answer (score 5):

They are not adding up immediately until recursion reaches to final expression. Here, what is happening on each step:

```
"5" + backwards("1234")
"5" + "4" + backwards("123")
"5" + "4" + "3" + backwards("12")
"5" + "4" + "3" + "2" + backwards("1")
"5" + "4" + "3" + "2" + "1" + backwards("")
"5" + "4" + "3" + "2" + "1" + ""
"54321"
```

Basically you are constructing a chain of return statements (aka [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)), they concatenate at the very end into "54321".

In above computation, I omitted `return` keywords. For e.g. `"5" + "4" + backwards("123")` looks like `return "5" + (return "4" + backwards("123"))` in reality.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in what `text[-1]` and `text[:-1]` give you. I think where you're getting tripped up is on the recursive aspect of it, which is the tricky part.

When you're working on recursive stuff it helps not to overthink it. I know that most of programming requires you to understand every little nuance of your code but recursion is different. If you try to think through a recursive function's call stack in your head you'll just get confused. Human brains aren't like computers. Our stacks can only get about three levels deep before we lose track.

So for this problem the way you want to think about it is something like this:

> "To reverse a string, you simply take the last character and put it at
>   the beginning of the reversified version of the remaining characters."

It seems like a nonsense statement because it's defined in terms of itself, but that's precisely what recursion is, a function that is defined in terms of itself.

So for you question, `text[-1]` gives you the last item in the list and `text[:-1]` give you the remaining characters.

As an example, if your list is `[1, 2, 3, 4]` then evaluating each recursive call would go something like this:

```
backwards([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

evaluates to

```
4 + backwards([1, 2, 3])
```

which evaluates to

```
4 + 3 + backwards[1, 2])
```

which evaluates to

```
4 + 3 + 2 + backwards([1])
```

which evaluates to

```
4 + 3 + 2 + 1
```

When I first answered this question, I thought the function you listed didn't work and you wanted one that did, so I threw one together real quick. When I wrote it, I literally typed out the quote I listed above into my text editor then wrote out the python code (which looks just like the one you have posted). I didn't step through each call in my head I just typed out the sentence then wrote some code that implemented that sentence.

Recursion takes some getting used to but once you kind of get how think recursively you can apply it to all kinds of problems.

Another example that might be a bit more straight forward would be a recursive function that sums up all the numbers in a list.

```
sum([1, 2, 3, 4]) => 10
```

So the statement for this would be

> To sum a list, add the first item in the list to the sum of the
>   remaining elements in the list.

The python would look like this:

```
def sum(a):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return a[0] + sum(a[1:])
```

Comment: The question isn't *how* to do it, but to understand how this particular code works as is.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this code works is due to how you're handling it.  As you correctly observe, `text[:-1]` would be the rest of the string *without* the last element.

This critical piece of code operates by appending the last element to the recursive result of appending the last element or an empty string to the rest of the string.

```
return text[-1] + backward(text[:-1])
```

The hint here is the recursive call to `backward`.  Treat `text[:-1]` as another string with the same rules as any other string.  If the string is empty, the empty string itself is returned; otherwise, you take the last element (denoted by `text[-1]`) from it, and pass along the remainder of the string to be dealt with on subsequent recursive calls.